# Creating a new variable based on numeric differences between two other variables in r

Tags: r

Here's an example dataset.

```
structure(list(vector1 = c(1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 
5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5), vector2 = c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a new variable 'Direction' based on differences between these numbers. I want to say something like:

if vector2 == vector1 or vector2 == vector1 +/- 1 than Direction == 'NS'

if vector2 < vector1 -1 or if vector 2 > vector1 + 1 than Direction == 'EW'

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: what if it neither of the two conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar solution is this (slightly simpler):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  vector1 = c(1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5),
  vector2 = c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)
)
```

Desired new column:

```
df$direction <- ifelse(df$vector1==vector2 | 
                         df$vector1==vector2 + 1 | 
                         df$vector1==vector2 - 1, "NS","EW")
```

Outcome:

```
df
   vector1 vector2 direction
1        1       4        EW
2        4       2        EW
3        4       3        NS
4        2       5        EW
5        1       3        EW
6        3       5        EW
7        2       2        NS
8        3       2        NS
9        4       3        NS
10       5       3        EW
11       3       4        NS
12       5       1        EW
13       5       4        NS
14       1       1        NS
15       4       2        EW
16       2       1        NS
17       4       2        EW
18       5       1        EW
19       2       1        NS
20       5       2        EW
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
df <- structure(list(vector1 = c(1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 
                       5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5), vector2 = c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 
                                                            3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                      -20L))


df$direction <- with(df,ifelse((vector2 == vector1) | (vector2 == (vector1 + 1)) | (vector2 == (vector1 - 1)), "NS", 
                   ifelse(vector2 < (vector1-1) | (vector2 > (vector1 + 1)),"EW", NA)))
```